# WCF Service public class available to consuming application

Tags: wcf

I am writing a WCF Service and inside the service application have a couple of classes... I want these to be available to the consuming application but it won't actually pass them back as a parameter, rather it will add them into a object array and then pass them back.  Seems the only way I can find to make available to .NET App is to have them as a parameter in a service method.

Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found answer, sorry:

add to IService

[ServiceKnownType(typeof())]